# where to put the log4j.properties file in case of JSP

Tags: jsp, log4j

i want to do logging through jsp page only. i have done all, but if i try to run it says,"log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (PinAuditor.jsp).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."

if that problem comes in case of java file, we place the log4j.properties in the src folder. 
now where should i put this in the case of jsp?

Comment: Example http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the classpath root, the same way as you would do for normal Java. The `src` folder is indeed one of the root folders covered by the classpath. Although writing Java code in JSP files is a bad practice, the Java code in JSP does absolutely not behave different from Java code in normal Java classes.

Comment: sorry, i tried but that one is not working. its giving the same warn msg. by classpath you mean to say the classes folder?